# Definition of a neighborhood in normed linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

This might be very stupid question, but I just realized that I haven't spotted a definition for a neighborhood in normed linear space.

Usually in topology one just states that neighborhood is open set of some space such that your point belongs into that open set.

But what if we are looking into normed linear spaces?

What is a neighborhood of a functional?

For example let $ \mathcal{R}$ be a normed linear space and take a point $y$ from it. What would be the neighborhood of this $y$?

Comment: A normed linear space is a metric space.  Use the [metric topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets.2C_topology_and_convergence) to define open sets which then define neigborhoods.

Comment: Umm, so open balls is the way to go?

Comment: $ \ $Yep.$ \ \ $

Comment: You can see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space#Topological_structure

Comment: A neighborhood base is enough to define a topology. Every point $x$ has a countable neighborhood base of the form $\{ y : \|y-x\| < 1/n\}$ for $n=1,2,3,4,\cdots$. How might you define a neighborhood of a functional? You can probably think of more than one way to define a neighborhood of a functional, such as, for a fixed $x$, considering all functions that near agree with the given one at $x$; finite intersections will then generate a neighborhood base; another way would be to use the norm and a uniform topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "inner product", , on a vector space automatically defines a "norm" by $||u||= \sqrt{<u,u>}$. An inner product, ||v||, automatically defines a "metric" by  d(u,v)= ||u- v||.  And a metric then automatically defines a topology by defining open sets in terms of unions and finite intersections of "neighborhoods" $N(p,\rho)= \{q| d(p,q)<\rho\}$.